# Suppress an after-install error in Chrome extension: "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In a Chrome extension, in `options.html` i have a `<select>` with some options user should set. In `options.js` i have a listener for this

```
document.getElementById('wptk').addEventListener('change', save_options);
```

But immediately after installation, befor user sets the options, there rises an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

How can i suppress it? Or i don't need?

[Manifest](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pAV1m1rkb7-06VkW4HuvcEGHSSJHveAJ), [options.html](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gCVHMLg9LGGuBeSwhhWe-788pluo6TQZ), [options.js](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1m-HRtgZXYtN7txZ9kUsEb8K0033gmV24), [popup.js](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kWqOgPknMCY9ztxa0cYclvYHLZ1Dplyh), [popup.html](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pcRTCOY74TAqx4xx2alrfUjjPDp-7D3U)

[image]

Comment: It means the script runs too early or in the wrong context. Show your manifest.json and options.html.

Comment: The problem is likely in popup.js. Remove the entire `content_scripts` section, it's not needed - you should use  `<script src=popup.js></script>` in popup.html.

Comment: Did so, deleted the whole `content_scripts` section - same error. Tried to include `popup.js` into `head` or into `body` - same error. Added popups to the post.

Comment: Move `<script src="popup.js"></script>` at the very end of the html. Also don't forget to reload the extension on `chrome://extensions` page and manually clear the errors in the card on that page because it displays all old errors too.

Comment: Moved `<script src="popup.js"></script>` just before closing `</body>`, deinstalled and reinstalled extension - same error. After selecting and saving an option and manual deleting of an error in `chrome://extensions` on extension page the error no longer appears. But immediately after installation it is still here.

Comment: The error should specify where it occurs and the source code line number. It may be background.js or psl.js.

Comment: Yes, sure, it specifies the file and the line, where the listener is, like on the screenshot in the post.

Comment: The error message says you're loading options.js in welcome.html. Don't do that.

Comment: I thought i need it for using options.html in iframe - now it works! Thank you! I have a very similar error now - should it become new thread?